# What are topics to avoid learning in Android altogether and what is good for understanding new concepts even though it is deprecated?

Tags: android

I am new to android but I haven't learnt android very well.Although for some of my previous projects which were poorly implemented, I used recycler view and never used a Listview.Is there any insights that I would gain from learning something like Listview and ListActivity which might be deprecated in the future.

This is because I did try learning a lot about Apache HTTP Client on Android just to see it deprecated in a few months.

Also Android seems to be a rapidly changing platform.Just yesterday I realised that the tutorials online on Tabbed Activity ad Navigation Drawer have a different representation of layout files than the one Android provides by default.Its all confusing!!

Comment: This question is somewhat opinion based, so don't expect any straight forward answers.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean bad or wrong, just that there is now a newer way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you learned to use the Apache HTTP Client on Android, then it means you googled around for a tutorial you could use and you went to one of the first results listed. This is perfectly understandable.

Unfortunately, using google is not always the best way to get to the latest tutorials, since older tutorials can sometimes have higher page ranks just because over time they've accumulated a very high number of inbound links.

For that reason, you should educate yourself about the general state of Android, and try to notice the latest changes. Having this overall knowledge should allow you to become better at Googling and filtering for the most up-to-date information.

- Every time a new version of android is released, read the [summary](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) of the changes. It's always worth reading and it's only a couple of pages long. Go back a few versions to see what you've missed so far.
- Watch the [Android DevBytes](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=android%20devbytes) on youtube. They're very short videos produced by Google. They're between 3 minutes and 10 minutes long. View the most recent first. They should give you a good overview of the latest changes.
- When browsing the official [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) documentation, know that you can filter by api level number. That's handy sometimes depending on what you're trying to do.
- Go to Android meetups, [Google Developers Groups](https://developers.google.com/groups/), and conferences, assuming there are some around near where you are. Learning the latest best practices is a social ongoing process.
- Learning the history of Android is not always a bad idea. For instance, the concept of a RecyclerView only builds on the previous concept of a ListView. And to me at least, knowing how things were done in the past helps me understand the current state of things.
- Do not rely on Google for everything. Some third party libraries are more current than Google's own libraries. http://square.github.io/#android
- "deprecated" doesn't mean that you can't use it, it just means that you shouldn't use it. Don't be so quick to dismiss "deprecated" functionality.
- That being said, Apache HTTP Client is probably past its expiration point. I know the Apache HTTP Client on Android was just removed from Android 6.0, but this change has been a long time coming. It has been deprecated for a couple of years now.